# Read consistency for different MySQL connections

Tags: mysql, concurrency, isolation-level

If I commit some changes from one connection and right after commit I will open a new connection is it possible that the changes made in first connection are not yet visible in this new connection.

I'm using MySQL with default isolation level - REPEATABLE READ.
If possible would be nice to have a reference to some documentation that explains this.

Thank you

Comment: Is this actually happening to you? Or is this just some research you want us to do for you

Comment: @RiggsFolly Yes, I observe this behavior in 20% of cases and I found out that other people sometimes have this problem but I couldn't find any explanation in the official documentation...

Comment: Can you give a very precise example of what you do and what you observe? I think with your scenario, you could create a failure state that is not allowed per sql standard (in your 2nd transaction, do a select (old data) and an update based on it (failure if its updating either old or new data)), which MySQL would not be able to prevent (as locks are released on commit). With some more  details, we may be able to pinpoint your problem (or at least ask for specific information or tests to do). My first guess in these situation is usually some connection pool behaviour - do you have one?

Comment: @Solarflare The situation is the following: a resource is created and stored in the database; then an event about this is fired to an external service which in turn tries to read this resource from a database using another connection (not directly but through an API which will use another database connection) - but it will be able to do so only after a while - first try sometimes will fail because resource (new row in the table) is not found. If we put a delay before processing the event then read will succeed with first try.

Comment: Do you have control/insight into the api? E.g., apis like to cache data, can that be the case here? Also, the api might keep a connection open (e.g. it might not open a new connection after the commit as stated in your question), and even might have a transaction open (so it even might to be required to send the old state if there was a previous read). Maybe enable the [MySQL query log](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/query-log.html) to get an idea about what and when the api (and the resource creation) actually sends queries to the database.